# Discard an already saved entity

Tags: breeze

I have a distributed system where users can make changes into one single database. To illustrate the problem, let's assume we have the following entities:

```
public class Product{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public List<ProductOwner> ProductOwners{get;set;}

}
public class ProductOwner{
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
  [Inversroperty("ProductOwners")]
  public Product Product{ get; set; }

  public int OwnerId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
  public Owner Owner{ get; set; }
}

public class Owner{
   public int Id{get;set;}
}
```

Let's also assume we have two users, `UserOne` and `UserTwo` connected to the system.
UserOne adds `Product1` and assigns `Owner1` as an owner. As a result, a new `ProductOwner1` is created with `key=[Product1.Id, Owner1.Id]`

UserTwo does the same operation, another instance `ProductOwner2` with `key=[Product1.Id, Owner1.Id]` is created. This will result in an EF exception on the server side, which is expected, as a row with `key=[Product1.Id, Owner1.Id]` already exists in the database.

**Question**
The issue above can be partly resolved by having some sort of real time data refresh on both `UserOne` and `UserTwo` machines (I am already doing this) and running a validation task on the server to ignore and not save entities that are already in the DB. 
The remaining issue is how to tell Breeze on 'userTwo' machine to mark `ProductOwner2` as saved and change its state from `Added` to `Unchanged`?

Comment: what ended up being the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an excellent question and has been raised enough that I wanted to chime in on how I would do it given the above scenario in hopes others can find a good way to accomplish this *from a Breeze.js perspective* as well.  This answer doesn't really address server logic so it is incomplete at best.

**Step 1 - Open a web socket**

First and foremost we need some way to tell the other connected clients that there has been a change.  SignalR is a great way to do this if you are using the ASP.NET MVC stack and there are a bunch of other tools.

The point is that we don't need to have a great way of passing data down and forcing it in to the client's cache, we just need a lightweight way to tell the client that some information has changed and if they are concerned with this to refresh something.  My recommendation in this area would be to use a payload that tells the client either what entity type and Id changed or give a resource to the client to let them know what collection of entities to refresh.  Two examples of a JSON payload that would work well here -

```
{
    "entityChanges": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "type": "product",
            "new": false
        },
        {
            "id": "234",
            "type": "product",
            "new": true
        }
    ],
    collectionChanges: [
        {
            "type": "productOwners"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this scenario we are simply telling the client that the products with Ids of `123` and `234` have changed, and that `234` happens to be a new entity.  We aren't pushing any data about *what properties* have changed to the client as that is their responsibility to decide whether to refresh or requery for data.  There is also the possibility of telling the client to refresh a whole collection like in the second array but I will focus on the first example.

**Step 2 - Handle the changes**

Ok we got a payload from our web socket that we need to pass to some analyzer to decide whether to requery.  My recommendation here is to check if that entity exists in cache, and if so, refresh it.  If a flag comes down in the JSON that says it is a new entity we probably *also* need to requery it.  Here is some basic logic -

```
function checkForChanges (payload) {
    var parsedJson = $.parse(payload);
    $.each(parsedJson.entityChanges, function (index, item) {
        // If it is a new entity,
        if (item.new === true) {
            // Go get it from the database
            manager.fetchEntityByKey(item.type, item.id)
                .then(fetchSucceeded).fail(fetchFailed);
        } else {

            // Check local cache first
            var localentity = manager.getEntityByKey(item.type, item.id);
            // And if we have a local copy already,
            if (localentity) {
                // Go refresh it from the database
                manager.fetchEntityByKey(item.type, item.id)
                    .then(fetchSucceeded).fail(fetchFailed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now there is probably some additional logic in your application that need to be handled but in a nut shell we are -

1. Opening up a lightweight connection to the client to listen for changes only
2. Creating a handler for when those changes occur
3. Applying some logic on how to query for or refresh the data

Some considerations here are you may want to use different merge strategies depending on various conditions.  For instance if the entity already has changes you may want to preserve changes, where as if it is a entity that is always in a state of flux you may want to overwrite changes.

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MergeStrategy.html

Hope this provides some insight, and if it doesn't answer your question directly I apologize for crowding up the answers : )

Comment: I am already doing all of this :) A result of more than 6 months of research. Now, I am facing the issue I asked above...

Comment: So would it be fair to state that you want to return to the second client that the product owner they created is a duplicate and resolve it with the entity from client1?  If it were me in this scenario I would probably want to blow the productOwner2 out of cache and instead requery for productOwner1 to ensure there aren't concurrency issues, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Most of the time, my implementation does this. `UserTwo` gets a signalR signal to go fetch the new entities - here, all is ok. Issues start to araise when `UserOne` and `UserTwo` do the same operation at the same time which results in some kind of race condition...

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to catch the entity framework / unique key constraint error on the breeze client and react by creating a new entity manager (using the [createEmptyCopy](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_createEmptyCopy) method), loading the relevant ProductOwner records and using them to determine which ProductOwner records in the original entityManager need to be set "unchanged" using the entity's entityAspect's [setUnchanged](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#method_setUnchanged) method.  Once this "synchronization" is done the save changes can be retried.

In other words, the client is optimistic the save will succeed but can recover if necessary.  The server remains oblivious to the potential race condition and has no custom code.

A brute force approach, apologies if I'm stating the obvious.

Comment: You can't just set the entity's saved state to `Unchanged` in the client side. It must come from the server which has the only single version of truth.

Comment: @GETah - I may have misunderstood.  I was replying to this: "The remaining issue is how to tell Breeze on 'userTwo' machine to mark ProductOwner2 as saved and change its state from Added to Unchanged?"

Comment: Yes but then how would you handle this if the save really fails? There must be some communication from the server down to the client to tell it which entities are fine to set to `Unchanged` and by Breeze I meant Breeze on the server and Breeze on the client. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I see what you mean now- my answer is incomplete.  You're looking for a way to communicate to the client that a particular ProductOwner entity already exists and should have it's state set to "unchanged".  I'll update my answer with an approach, although not super elegant.

Comment: Exactly :) Thanks for taking a look

Comment: +1. Thank you for your answer, let's see if there is no other elegant way of achieving this